# Enable Bundling Optimization Only for Certain Directories

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible with .NET bundling to only bundle certain JS files, preferably by using a wildcard to filter directories?

During debug mode, I would like to view all the individual files, not all the files combined into one.

I have to keep `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` set to true to enable Angular template caching.

I've tried `Transforms.Clear()`, but apparently that only applies to minification.

Maybe something similar to what this guy is doing, but with out having to install the VS plugin
https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/wiki/Unbundling-scripts-for-debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Bundle Optimization in debug mode and when you deploy your application using release mode it will enable automatically. Just add the following line at the end of **RegisterBundles** method in **BundleConfig.cs**

```
#if !DEBUG
     BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

Comment: Please re-read the question "I have to keep BundleTable.EnableOptimizations set to true to enable Angular template caching"

Comment: There is no way in which you can only optimize selective bundles. You have to optimize or not.